# if Index of a combobox is equal to the index of your <List>?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Some info:** In my combobox are details of my `list<Create>`, when people click on a row in my combobox, it should be able to edit things from the selected row (the editable things will be parsed in textboxes).

**Question:** is it possible to get the index of the comboxbox and check if that index matches with the index of my `List<Create> Characters` so I can return a specific row of items?

```
    private void cbSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Create character in Characters)
        {
            if(cbSummary.SelectedIndex == ?? )
        }
    }
```

The thing that came to mind was building this, but I'm not so sure yet.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking?

Comment: Why don´t you simply call `myList[theIndex]`?

Comment: windows forms, wpf, or...?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Windows Forms

Comment: if your List is used as the DataSource for the combobox (or listbox) then the selecteditem will **be** the correct item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using indexer:

```
var createList = new List<Create>();
// Populate list

var selectedListItem = createList[cbSummary.SelectedIndex];
```